# AWS 1 vcpu is equal to how many cores?

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, prometheus

Im trying to set resource limits on some of the deployments in my k8 cluster in AWS,but i was little confused with the relation between Ec2 vcpu vs actual cores.

actaully im running a prometheus components as multiple pods ,so how can i derive the resource limit values for prometheus pods?

Like how to derive memory & cpu numbers for request and limit

Answer (score 3):

The docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container#meaning-of-cpu) define the meaning of what Kubernetes considers as 1 CPU. 1 AWS vCPU is equivalent to 1 CPU unit in Kubernetes.